# How to setup a custom name to esp32 com port (serial port) unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arduino, esp32

Below is my sample program. I like to know how to set up a name for the serial port communication com port. This meaning When I connected esp32 using Bluetooth on my system it shows certain ports are using like COM9 or COM10 etc.  when I scan the ports using unity c# code

```
public void deviceCheck()
    {
        names=SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        foreach(string port in names)
            {
                Debug.Log(port);
                
            }
    }
```

it shows only the connected ports, not any name. Is there any way to setup a name for the connecting serial port of ESP32 and find the serial port name using unity c#